# how to fix error " violated - parent key not found"

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am updating table tleaves.

While updating this table I need to insert data to 2 tables one after the other.

SMS_DAILY_STATUS , SMS_LEAVES.

status_id id the foreign key for SMS_LEAVES.

I have written code for trigger like this.

```
if isemp > 0 then
    if applieddays = 0.5 then
        insert into sms_emp_daily_Status (STATUS_ID, EMP_ID, STATUS_DATE, PROD_ID, WORK_TYPE, ENTRY_BY, ENTRY_DATE, STN_OR_PLACE_ID,
        WORK_HRS, JOURNEY_HRS, STN_OR_PLACE_ID1,  CATEGORY, ENTRY_DATE_IN_APP, SOURCE_FROM, ALOG_ID)
        valueS (CSONLINE.EMP_STATUS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :old.ID_NO, :old.FROMDATE , -1, 6, 'TAMS', sysdate, 5216, 240,0,3003,0, sysdate,'TAMS',CSONLINE.ALOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL);

        Insert into sms_leaves (LEAVE_ID, CAUSE, STATUS_ID)  
        VALUES(CSONLINE.LEAVE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :old.REASON,sms_emp_daily_Status.STATUS_ID);
    end if;
```

It is giving me error. I should insert status_id of SMS_DAILY_STATUS to SMS_LEAVES.

Please help me. I am new to Triggers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Triggers are just handlers that fire some code when an event occurs (insert, delete etc.).  They are just PL/SQL code.  So your basic problem is foreign key constraint that is violated.  Solve it as if you would solve it without triggers.

Comment: In second `insert` try to use `csonline.emp_status_seq.currval`.

Comment: Thanku sir, it works.@PonderStibbons